# Reach a value provider from HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, value-provider

How can I reach a value from a module in my HTML? Like `module.value("myvalue", true)` and in HTML `<div ng-show="myvalue">Hello</div>`.

**Edit**

OK, one solution was to change the value to an object instead of a primitive, like this: `module.value("myvalue", {value: true})` and `<div ng-show="myvalue.value">Hello</div>` and then include in the controller `$scope.myvalue = myvalue` and inject `myvalue` in the argument list of the controller.

Comment: I think the latter half of your solution is all you need. That is, it need not be an object.

Comment: @david004 Ah, but I actually needed to update the value from a directive. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

If myvalue is a primitive type, then you should use a constant:

```
module.constant('myvalue', true);
```

myvalue is then injectable:

```
module.controller('controller', function(myvalue) {
});
```